# fullcalendar js when a long event added the title show up every week. Is that a way to make the title show up once?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

fullcalendar js when a long event added the title show up every week. Is that a way to make the title show up once ? I try the code on v5 and v6 the title show up every week.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<!-- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals-->
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@6.1.10/index.global.min.js'> 
</script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/daygrid@6.1.10/index.global.min.js'></script>
<script>

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      events: [
            {
                title: 'Testing 1 the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.',
                start: '2024-01-02',
                end: '2024-02-03',
                color: 'green'
            }
        ],
    });
    calendar.render();
  });

</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what it look like when render the page at the browser      [image]

Comment: It works very well Thanks a lot. If the event started at Saturday the title will only a portion of title show up. I have to solve that issues too. Will be nice if I can expand the title to show in full length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used this library, I didn't understand much, but I discovered that there is an event called **eventContent** that runs once for each line added. And that he always uses the same object. So I created a list that skips the first element and the next time it identifies the same object instead of playing the title it creates an empty element.

This solved the problem in your example, but test it well in a real environment with more information and I emphasize that it must be the worst way to do it haha.

[Content Injection - Docs | FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/content-injection)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var ignoreFirstList = [];
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    events: [
          {
              title: 'Testing 1 the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.',
              start: '2024-01-02',
              end: '2024-02-03',
              color: 'green'
          }
      ],
      eventContent: function (arg) {
          var obj = arg.event._def

          if (!ignoreFirstList.includes(obj)) {
              ignoreFirstList.push(obj)
              return true
          }

          // create empty span (but with height > 0)
          var span = document.createElement("span")
          span.textContent = obj.title[0] || "W"
          span.style.opacity = 0
          span.style.userSelect = "none"

          var arrayOfDomNodes = [span]
          return { domNodes: arrayOfDomNodes }
      },
  });
  calendar.render();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@6.1.10/index.global.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/daygrid@6.1.10/index.global.min.js"></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```